# I can't transfer the file to the database (longblob)

Tags: php, mysql

I ran into such a problem. I wrote a website on a vps server and I need to transfer an audio file to the database. If I transfer using php, all data is written except the file itself.
I have files in the audio folder on the server side that need to be transferred to the database.
I have configured the database configuration file (MySQL), Apache and php.ini for files up to 100 MB in size. And he set a long waiting time. But still does not want to transfer the file.

My php code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Ошибка подключения: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id'] ?? null;
$path_ = "c:";
$file_status = 1;

if (!is_null($user_id) && !empty($files)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_files (user_id, name_, path_, file_status, on_file) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = $directory . $file_name;
        $file_content = file_get_contents($file_path);
        $null = NULL;
        $stmt->bind_param("sssis", $user_id, $file_name, $path_, $file_status, $null);
        $stmt->send_long_data(4, $file_content); // Отправляем содержимое файла
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I also suggested rereading it from another PC in python and I succeeded.
I tried to transfer a very small text file, but it didn't work out.
It is written to the database as NULL
File access is correct. I managed to read them.

My Modules:
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

The rights and owners of my files. They seem to be correct too
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbKzh.png)

Comment: Have you considered the max_allowed_packet size on the mysql side? See the example (using a loop to send the file in gradual chunks) and the notes in the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php . Also, please add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `new mysqli()` command in case this code is causing a SQL error, and you just aren't noticing.

Comment: `I have configured the database configuration file (MySQL), Apache and php.ini for files up to 100 MB in size`...for this is would help us to know exactly what settings you have configured, and with what values. Otherwise we can't know if you've done everything correctly or not.

Comment: "does not want to transfer the file" always also tell what *does* happen

Comment: Php.ini: memory_limit = 2048M, max_input_time = 600, max_execution_time = 300, output_buffering = 4096, log_errors_max_len = 1024, post_max_size = 100M, upload_max_filesize = 200M, max_file_uploads = 200, default_socket_timeout = 600, [MySQLi]: mysqli.max_persistent = -1, mysqli.allow_persistent = On, mysqli.max_links = -1.

Comment: I was also able to add an entry to my table via python. There were no problems.
Using php, it turns out to add an entry, but without a file

Comment: Apache2.conf: Timeout 3000, MaxKeepAliveRequests 100, KeepAliveTimeout 5

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in the configuration of either apache2 or php7.4

Comment: What settings do I need to make in order to correctly transfer files to mysql?
As I understand it, I have a server-side error.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Also, please check whether the file is available in PHP (which means that Apache itself is not the problem)

Comment: If this even didn't work with a **small* text file, check for more details. For example, the documentation for `send_long_data` uses `b` for the parameter type. Also, what's the point in binding `NULL` first to that parameter and then binding it again?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Changed the approach when transferring data: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_files (user_id, name_, path_, file_status, on_file) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,  FROM_BASE64(?))");

   

    foreach ($files as $file_name) {

        $file_path = $directory . $file_name;

        $file_content = file_get_contents($file_path);

        $encoded_content = base64_encode($file_content);

        $stmt->bind_param("sssis", $user_id, $file_name, $path_, $file_status, $encoded_content);

        $stmt->execute();

    }

Comment: If you solved it that's great - please add an Answer below for others in future so they can search and vote on it. Comments cannot be searched and you cannot gain reputation points from them. See also [answer] - thanks!